# Как создать класс/интерфейс, который в зависимости от входящего объекта будет возвращать объект, с определенным методами?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Надо создать класс/интерфейс, который в зависимости от входящего объекта будет возвращать тоже объект, но с определенным методами в нем. Пример:

Интерфейс - рабочий
Классы: слесарь, сантехник, плотник

нужно что-то типа:

```
class РабочийHadler
{
    public РабочийHadler(Рабочий рабочий){}
    public static void сваркаПерекрытий(){}
    public static void починкаСмесителя(){}
    public static void резкаПодсвечника(){}
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main( String ... args )
    {
        Рабочий раб1 = new Слесарь();
        РабочийHandler handler1 = РабочийHandler( раб1 );

        handler1.сваркаПерекрытий();
        handler1.починкаСмесителя(); // compile error
    }
}
```

Вот. Чтобы handler1-у была доступна только ф-ция "сваркаПерекрытий()"  и ничего большего. Через какой паттерн это реализовывается.... Ну или можно без паттерна?

Comment: посмотрите шаблон `visitor`, - в кратце суть шаблона в том что к любому обьекту можно применить действующее лицо - визитор который выполнит определенные действия (если сможет), если не разберетесь пишите, опишу подробнее

Comment: вот это именно то, что я хотел! спасибо! может я остальных запутал, но и вам спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, зачем так делать? Какая задача предполагает такой подход? И как вы в рантайме будете определять, доступен ли тот или иной метод в том или ином `Handler`-е?

Во-вторых, решить можно так: делаем несколько классов-`Handler`-ов, в котроых нужные методы выполняем, а в недоступных выкидываем какой-нибудь `UnimplementedMethodException`.

Comment: начальник поставил задачу - один интерфейс, который будут имплементить классы... через него будет построена бизнес-логика... как он сказал: нужен интерфейс Map (не путать со стандартным) от которого произойдут MapCSV, MapWebService, MapDB... они будут нужны для мапировки данных... как-то так

Comment: вы пока пытались обьяснить что-к чему сразу всплыло узкое место в названиях классов, - лучше сразу называйте `Mapping` или `Mapper` вместо `Map`

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, тут нужны отдельные интерфейсы:

```
interface IСварщик {
  public static void сваркаПерекрытий(){}
}
```

А выдавать объекты будет фабрика

```
class CFactory {
  public static IСварщик createСварщик();
}
```

Если нужен общий интерфейс, то он должен содержать общие методы:

interface IРабочий {
  public void работать();
}

Пусть все рабочие наследуются от CРабочий, реализующего IРабочий.

Comment: в том то и дело, что общие методы нужно реализовать, а по логике, они иметь должны разные названия и, тем паче, параметры

Comment: все таки у меня с Visitor-ом не получилось. кажется, что это слегка не то. а вот на счет фабрики - более менее.

Answer (score 2):

пример использования шаблона визитор адаптированый под ваши данные.

рабочие:

```
// базовый интерфейс рабочего
interface Visitable {

    Object visit(Visitor visitor) throws Exception;
}

// сварщик
class A implements Visitable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "сварщик";
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(Visitor visitor) throws Exception {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }

}

// столяр
class B implements Visitable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "столяр";
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(Visitor visitor) throws Exception {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }

}

// маляр
class C implements Visitable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "маляр";
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(Visitor visitor) throws Exception {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }

}
```

визиторы (определяют действия рабочих, точнее действия над ними):

```
// базовый визитор, на данный момент умет обрабатывать корректно только "сварщиков" + общий тип
interface Visitor {

    Object visit(A a) throws Exception;

    Object visit(Visitable visitable) throws Exception;

}

// визитор который умеет писать все в лог
// применимый ко всем типам "рабочих"
class DumpVisitor extends NoActionVisitor {

    @Override
    protected void handle(Visitable visitable) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        System.out.println("dumping " + visitable);
    }

}

// визитор который ничего не умеет
// применимый ко всем типам "рабочих"
class NoActionVisitor implements Visitor {

    protected void handle(Visitable visitable) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("action is not supported for the type = " + visitable);
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(A visitable) throws Exception {
        handle(visitable);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(Visitable visitable) throws Exception {
        handle(visitable);
        return null;
    }

}

// имплементация визитора c функционалом применимым только к сварщикам
// пример: сварка перекрытий
class CustomVisitor extends NoActionVisitor implements Visitor {

    @Override
    public Object visit(A a) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("do specific action on worker = " + a);
        return null;
    }

}
```

пример использования:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // сварщик + no action visitor
        test(new A(), new NoActionVisitor());

        // столяр + no action visitor
        test(new B(), new NoActionVisitor());

        // маляр + no action visitor
        test(new C(), new NoActionVisitor());

        // дамп визитор
        test(new A(), new DumpVisitor());
        test(new B(), new DumpVisitor());
        test(new C(), new DumpVisitor());

        // визитор только для сварщиков
        test(new A(), new CustomVisitor());
        test(new B(), new CustomVisitor());
        test(new C(), new CustomVisitor());
    }

    public static void test(Visitable visitable, Visitor visitor) {
        System.out.println("Testing visitable = " + visitable + ", visitor = " + visitor.getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            visitable.visit(visitor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Got error = " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: а для каких полезных целей применяется этот шаблон?

Comment: с одной стороны шаблон немного усложняет понимаени кода с другой стороны код с применением этого шаблона очень гибкий - легко добавить как новые `visitable` так и `visitor'ы` - как следствие удобно применять в приложениях где требуется дополнительня гибкость архитектуры, в приложениях в которых заранее не известны многие требования. к тому же с помощью этоо паттерна легко избавится от многочисленых `if+instanceof`конструкций

Comment: 2 jmu,
спасибо Вам громадное... два часа сидел смотрел Ваш код, разбирал, рисовал UML-ки.... и дошло... построил для своей задачи! все супер! и, действительно, никаких if+instanceof... главное, чтобы начальнику понравилось))

кстати, я изначально смотрел книжный вариант (Стелтинг "Применение шаблонов Java") и вики-вариант (может и моветон для шаблонов, но все же)... и там сказано следующее:
Минусы: 
...
Затруднено добавление новых классов, поскольку нужно обновлять иерархию посетителя и его сыновей.

Comment: @nightin_gale, а теперь представьте, сколько ошибок будет в программах, которые, пользуясь *подобным инструментом* будут писать, а тем более сопровождать (по указанию Вашего же начальника) не столь дотошные, как Вы, программисты.

Никогда не забывайте про KISS принцип.

Comment: не слышал о KISS, прочел первые строчки лурка - позабавило) простите, я не аналитик, и опытом еще не оброс... просто хотелось попробовать использовать шаблоны, ведь их не зря же создали... стоило или нет - решать не мне... вы бы тогда уж и свое что предложили) мне интересена ваша версия.

Comment: > Минусы: ... Затруднено добавление новых классов, поскольку нужно обновлять иерархию посетителя и его сыновей.

да есть такой минус, но насколько сильно он повлияет на ваш код зависит только от вас. даже в приведеном мной примере видно что если наследовать все визиторы от `NoActionVisitor` то эта проблема исчезает и у вас при добавлении новых визитейбл в интерфейс визитора поменяется только этот класс + несколько конкретных визиторов которые должны обрабатывать этот тип

Comment: > Никогда не забывайте про KISS принцип.
если повышение сложности это именно то чего хочет начальство... с другой стороны, не считаю что использование шаблона визитор в коде должно пугать программиста (который теоретически должен знать шаблоны от А до Я)